# Ansible-Playbook unable to install MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, ansible

I have an ansible-playbook file that is meant to install a bunch of packages onto an Ubuntu VM (22.04), including MongoDB. However, I receive the following error when I run it:

> fatal: [myserver]: FAILED! => {"cache_update_time": 1651714552, "cache_updated": true, "changed": false, "msg": "'/usr/bin/apt-get -y -o "Dpkg::Options::=--force-confdef" -o "Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold"       install 'mongodb-org'' failed: E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.\n", "rc": 100, "stderr": "E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.\n", "stderr_lines": ["E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages."], "stdout": "Reading package lists...\nBuilding dependency tree...\nReading state information...\nSome packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have\nrequested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable\ndistribution that some required packages have not yet been created\nor been moved out of Incoming.\nThe following information may help to resolve the situation:\n\nThe following packages have unmet dependencies:\n mongodb-org-mongos : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1) but it is not installable\n mongodb-org-server : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1) but it is not installable\n mongodb-org-shell : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1) but it is not installable\n", "stdout_lines": ["Reading package lists...", "Building dependency tree...", "Reading state information...", "Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have", "requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable", "distribution that some required packages have not yet been created", "or been moved out of Incoming.", "The following information may help to resolve the situation:", "", "The following packages have unmet dependencies:", " mongodb-org-mongos : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1) but it is not installable", " mongodb-org-server : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1) but it is not installable", " mongodb-org-shell : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1) but it is not installable"]}

These are the tasks responsible for MongoDB in the ansible-playbook:

```
---
- hosts: myserver
  become: true
  remote_user: admin
  vars_files:
     - default.yml

  tasks:
    - name: "Install aptitude"
      apt:
        name: aptitude
        state: latest
        update_cache: true

    - name: "Import MongoDB public key"
      apt_key:
         url: "https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-5.0.asc"
         state: present

    - name: "Add MongoDB repository"
      apt_repository:
         filename: '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-5.0.list'
         repo: "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/5.0 multiverse"
         state: present
         update_cache: yes

    - name: "Install MongoDB"
      apt: 
         name: mongodb-org
         state: present
         update_cache: yes
```

It should be noted that it's at the "Install MongoDB" task that the ansible-playbook fails. The tasks before execute fine.

Any thoughts on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: This looks like an `apt` problem, not an Ansible problem. Do you get the same errors if you try to `apt-get install mongodb-org` at the command line?

Comment: Hmm, yeah. I do get the same errors when I try to install MongoDB on the command line. Saying that some packages (mongodb-org-mongos, mongodb-org-server, mongodb-org-shel) have unmet dependencies. All of them Depending on libssl1.1 but "it is not installable".

Comment: Take a look at an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73494370/799379) I posted about the error - not specifically for MongoDB, it might help you resolve this specific dependency issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, after some intense googling it appears that the issue I'm having is related to the OS that my VM is running - Ubuntu 22.04.

This [MongoDB team member post on a community forum](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/installing-mongodb-over-ubuntu-22-04/159931/7) about the same issue basically says that since 22.04 is pretty new the MongoDB team hasn't gotten to releasing a compatible package for it, yet. His post is 8 days old as of writing this. The MongoDB team member also advises against trying to merge varying packages together that are meant for different OS versions.

So, really, it looks like my only option is to revert back to an earlier OS version.

I hope this helps anyone else experiencing the same issue!